# Getting ID attribute from an Element.tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

What is the best way to get the ID value (2758769 in below example) from a BeautifulSoup Element Tag and assign to a variable?

```
type(an_element)
Out[13]: bs4.element.Tag

an_element
Out[14]: <span class="addr"><a href="p.php?q=Ascot+Vale&amp;sta=vic&amp;id=2758769&amp;address=1%2F39+Sandown+Road%2C+Ascot+Vale" target="_blank">1/39 Sandown Road</a></span>
```

*an_element.get('id')* returns none.

Comment: this element doesn't have `id` - it has url which has string `id=` but it is not `id` of tag. You should `get(href)` and search value in this text using standard string functions like `split()` - or use regex. Eventually you could use `urllib.parse.parse_qs('q=Ascot+...')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This element doesn't have `id`. It has `url` which has string `id=` but it is not `id` of tag.

You should `get("href")` and search value in this text using standard string functions like `split()` or regex. Or you can use `urllib.parse.parse_qs('q=Ascot+...')`

```
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<span class="addr"><a href="p.php?q=Ascot+Vale&amp;sta=vic&amp;id=2758769&amp;address=1%2F39+Sandown+Road%2C+Ascot+Vale" target="_blank">1/39 Sandown Road</a></span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

href = soup.find('a').get('href')

args = href.split('?')[1]

data = urllib.parse.parse_qs(args)

print(data['id'][0])
```

---

**EDIT:** The same using `split()`

```
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<span class="addr"><a href="p.php?q=Ascot+Vale&amp;sta=vic&amp;id=2758769&amp;address=1%2F39+Sandown+Road%2C+Ascot+Vale" target="_blank">1/39 Sandown Road</a></span>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

href = soup.find('a').get('href')

args = href.split('?')[1]

id_ = args.split('id=')[1].split('&')[0]

print(id_)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.  Let me test these out so I understand them, will report back

Comment: Is it possible to have this in one line?                      the_id = urllib.parse.parse_qs(args)
                    the_id = (the_id['id'][0])

Comment: yes, put first line in second line -  `the_id = urllib.parse.parse_qs(args)['id'][0]` But it make code less readable. Better to use name `data = ...` in first line to make it more readble .

Answer (score 2):

You just need to extract url and parse the query parameters.
Another way with regex:

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import re

 soup = BeautifulSoup('<span class="addr"><a href="p.php?q=Ascot+Vale&amp;sta=vic&amp;id=2758769&amp;address=1%2F39+Sandown+Road%2C+Ascot+Vale" 
    target="_blank">1/39 Sandown Road</a></span>',"html.parser")
 links = soup.findAll('a', href=True)
 for link in links:
    href = link['href']
    a = re.search("id=.*&",href)
    if a:
      x = a.group(0)
      x = x[:-1]
      print(x)
```